# How to check multiple conditions for calculated fields in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

In a SharePoint calculated field how do I check two things?

I have the following which checks field Est OpMargin and if less than 20 sets field to BG but I would also if less than 17 set it to RG

=IF([Est OpMargin]<20,"BG","")

Answer (score 1):

Nest the IFs:

```
=IF([Est OpMargin]<17, "RG",   IF([Est OpMargin]<20,"RG","")   )
```

In SharePoint 2007 and 2010 you can nest 7 levels deep, and 2013 and later you can next 19 levels.

Answer (score 0):

The Formula below for your reference:

```
=IF(And([Est OpMargin]>=17,[Est OpMargin]<20),"BG",IF([Est OpMargin]<17, "RG",""))
```

[image]